# Django - Save and Manage a Project-wide Setting

Tags: python, django

My Django project allows it's users to choose, for example, a color, to a certain page.I want the change to **not** be dependent on the user, meaning that,the changes one user makes affects ALL of the other users, how do I store this *color* variable, and how do I change it?

thx

Comment: You could create a database table with the RGB for the color of each page I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store color in a separate model, and store its foreign key in all user models.

```
class Color(models.Model):

    value = StringField()

class User(models.Model):

    ...
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be different for each user then?

Comment: No, it does not need to be. It is your wish if you want to store same color in different users or not

Comment: i may have been misunderstood. i want the setting to **not** be dependent on the user.

Comment: What does it matter, you can use same color for all users anyway

Comment: the thing is i want users to be able to change the colors for everybody. as if there was this "global" varaible *color* that was stored somewhere and could be changed.

Comment: reviewed this after 2 years of django-ing and I'm ashamed of myself. this is a great answer :) (we actually ended up using singleton models)